# Linear Transformations from Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors 4

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation $f: V → V$ given by 
$$f(u) = \frac{-d^2u (x)}{dx^2}$$

Where $V$ is the vector space of all continuously differentiable functions on the interval $0\le x \le L$ with $L$ a positive number. Find the possible eigenvalues $\
\lambda$ of $f(u) = \lambda u$ subject to the condition that $ u(x=0)=u(x =L)=0$. For the smallest two eigenvalues find the corresponding eigenfunction $u(x)$ normalized such that

$$\int_0^L dx |u(x)|^2 = 1$$

I have no idea what to do. I know I'm supposed to split it up into three parts but I can't seem to make sense of it. Can someone please give me some guidance? I've attached a picture of the actual problem [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jsmn.png)

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: You'd better take $V$ to be the space of infinitely differentiable functions.  If $u$ is only continuously differentiable, $f(u)$ might not exist at all.  If $u$ is only $k$ times continuously differentiable, $f(u)$ would be only $k-2$ times continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenfunctions are those functions such that $Vu = \lambda u$
and $V=-\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$

$u'' = -\lambda u$

There are only a few forms u can take on.
$u= e^{kx}, u= e^{-kx},u= \sin(kx), u= \cos(kx)$
where $k = \sqrt{|\lambda|}$

Next condition $u(0) = u(L) = 0,  u$ is a sin function.

$u = \sin(\frac{n\pi}{L} x)$

I am going to leave the rest to you.

Comment: Do i split this up into 3 parts (λ=0, λ<0 and λ>0) after this? or do i only focus on the "middle" part from 0 = λ?

Comment: The cases are done from the differential equation step, for lambda zero you have all functions whose second derivative is zero...ie straight lines

Comment: No, if $\lambda < 0$ then u would be an exponential function.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start by solving the differential equation $-u'' = \lambda u$.  Do the cases $\lambda = 0$, $\lambda < 0$ and $\lambda > 0$ separately.